# Markov chains - communicating states

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

If we are given a markov chain and have to decide if states intercommunicate with one another, do we need to consider a state communicating with itself.

E.g. with
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0.3 & 0 & 0.7 \\
    0 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
    0.5 & 0.5 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
it is clear $1 \rightarrow 2$, $2 \rightarrow 3$  and so on... . But, do we need to say that $1 \rightarrow 1$, $2 \rightarrow 2$ and $3 \rightarrow 3$

I have never seen it written in an example nor does the definition suggest we should consider it. So, is it just always the case that states communicate with themselves?

Comment: To check irreducibility you just check there is a path from every state to every other (different) state. If there is a path from 1 to 2 and a path from 2 to 1, then certainly there is a loop from 1 to itself.